# How can you make a region of a GWT DockLayoutPanel bleed into another?

Tags: css, gwt

I use a `DockLayoutPanel` to split my screen in a left navigation column and a center area. My problem is that the app skinning requires that a selected tab in the navigation column "overwrite" a 1 pixel wide column of the central area. Is there a way to setup my `DockLayoutPanel` to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my answer. The key is to use a `LayoutPanel` instead of the `DockLayoutPanel`. For example:

```
<g:LayoutPanel>
    <g:layer left="100px" right="0px" >
        <g:LayoutPanel ui:field='centralContainer' />
    </g:layer>
    <g:layer left="0px" width="101px">
        <g:FlowPanel ui:field='navContainer' />
    </g:layer>
</g:LayoutPanel>
```

Would make the nav bar bleed 1 pixel into the central container. The order is important here since it guarantees that the nav bar will overwrite the content of the central container.